# ctypes calling function with windows datatypes arguments

Tags: python, ctypes

Could someone help me how should I call the following function using ctypes python library:

```
DWORD myfunc(LPCSTR a,BYTE b, LPBYTE c, LPDWORD d, LPCBYTE *e,DWORD LEN)
```

How should I declare and initialize the arguments of the mentioned functions? Could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
from ctypes.wintypes import *
```

It has most of the types you want.